# Is there a way to trigger an action when a table structure is modified?

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I need to perform an action when the structure of a specific table is modified (a column is added or deleted). Ideally I would like to then modify another table, but sending an email to let us know that the table was modified would be sufficient. Similar to a trigger, but triggers only handle if the table's data is changed (update, insert, delete). Is there any way to accomplish this in MySql?

Comment: Not using MySQL functionalities. You will need to build your own solution.

Comment: There is no DDL triggers in MySQL.

Comment: Write an event that daily checks the table structures against data in a table and then update another table, if daily isn't enough make twice a day or hourly

Comment: If you need immediate notification, you could do it with a CDC (change data capture) tool. Basically a kind of binlog-tailing functionality, watching for any DDL statements. But this is not a MySQL-only solution. You'd need a CDC like Debezium.

Comment: Thanks all. So I'd need to write a separate script and run it regularly, or use an external tool, and there's nothing built in to MySQL for this functionality.